# when developing a gem with a executable binary fails to require files that live in the lib dir

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am developing a gem called `I19`. It is supposed to have a CLI. So in `bin/i19` and I `require "i19"`.
And from the file `lib/i19.rb` I do require files files placed in `lib/i19/`.

If I do `bundle console` everything works, but when I try to execute the binary file (I'm doing `rake install; i19 help`) I get this error: `require': cannot load such file -- i19/scanners/pattern_scanner (LoadError)`

This is how my files look like:

```
# bin/i19
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "thor"
require "i19"

module I19
  class CLI < Thor
  end
end

I19::CLI.start

# lib/i19.rb
require "i19/version"
require "i19/commands"
require "i19/scanners/pattern_scanner"
require "i19/scanners/pattern_with_scope_scanner"

module I19
end

# lib/scanners/pattern_scanner.rb
require 'i19/scanners/base_scanner'

module I19::Scanners
  class PatternScanner < BaseScanner
    # ...
  end
end
```

I don't understand why it works from the console but it doesn't from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer myself. The problem was not with the ruby code but the way the gem gets compiled.

My `gemspec` file looks like this

```
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'i19/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  # ...
  spec.files         = `git ls-files`.split($/)
  # ...
end
```

the problem is that `git ls-files` is not listing untracked files. Once I did `git add lib/i19/scanners/pattern_scanner.rb` it worked.

It makes me then think that my workflow of manually testing the CLI might not be the best, ie `rake install; i19 update` . Is there a better way?